# How to change 3D pie chart segment value at run time in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, pie-chart, android-sqlite

i want to create pie chart based on db values and while adjusting the slider i have to change pie chart i created it pie chart and got slider adjustable value. My code is,

```
   PieChartDefalut.java

   package com.exae.url;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.CheckBox;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import android.widget.SeekBar;
   import android.widget.Spinner;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;


   public class PieChartDefalut extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnItemSelectedListener
  {
private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "chartdb";
private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "piechart3d";
  SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;
  String year;
    double value;
    LinearLayout ll,ll1;
    Spinner my_spinner;

    ImageView pieChart;
    View my_vew;
    int count=0;
    String value_arr[]={};
    static String[] my_year={};
    static int[] my_values={};
    static int my_values_length=0;
    static int my_year_length=0;
    String mUrl;
    String label="";
private WebView googleChartView;
static String urlGoogleChart = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=300x150&";

 static String[] urlyear;
 static int[] urlvalues;
 SeekBar mSeekBar;
   TextView mProgressText;
  Button bt;
   int progress1=0;
   int progress2=0;
   Cursor c,c1;
   int b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.url);
  mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
  mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
  mProgressText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress);
 bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
  ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my);
  ll1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_linear);
  my_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);

try {
    sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " (Year VARCHAR(5),Value DOUBLE(5));"); 
    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('2001',5);");
    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('2002',25);");
    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('2003',15);");
    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('2004',25);");
    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('2005',25);");
     c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT Year,Value FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME , null);

     final int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("Year");
    final int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("Value");
    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                 year = c.getString(Column1);
                 value = c.getDouble(Column2);


                 System.out.println(year);
                 System.out.println(value);

            }while (c.moveToNext());

        } 
    }

    int columncount=c.getCount();

    System.out.println("count------>"+columncount);


         my_year = new String[columncount];

        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {                       
            for (int i = 0; i < columncount; i++)
            {
                my_year[i] = c.getString(Column1);
                System.out.println("database value-----"+i);
                System.out.println(my_year[i]);
                c.moveToNext();
            }           
        }



         my_values = new int[columncount];

        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {                       
            for (int j = 0; j < columncount; j++)
            {
                my_values[j] = c.getInt(Column2);
                System.out.println("database value-----"+j);
                System.out.println(my_values[j]);
                c.moveToNext();
            }           
        }


        my_year_length=my_year.length;
        System.out.println("string length----->"+my_year_length);

        for(int k=0;k<my_year_length;k++)
        {
            System.out.println("array stored values----------->"+my_year[k]);
        }


       my_values_length=my_values.length;
        System.out.println("string length----->"+my_values_length);

        for(int k1=0;k1<my_values_length;k1++)
        {
            System.out.println("array stored values----------->"+my_values[k1]);
        }


googleChartView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);


StringBuffer urlyear = new StringBuffer();

for(int i=0;i<my_year_length;i++)
{
if(i == (my_year_length - 1 ))
urlyear.append(my_year[i]);
else
urlyear.append(my_year[i]+"|");
}

StringBuffer urlvalues = new StringBuffer();

for(int j=0;j<my_values_length;j++) 
{
if(j == (my_values_length - 1 ))
urlvalues.append(my_values[j]);
else
urlvalues.append(my_values[j]+",");
}


mUrl = urlGoogleChart+"chl="+urlyear+"&chd=t:"+urlvalues;
googleChartView.loadUrl(mUrl);  



 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,my_year);

 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

 my_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

 my_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 System.out.println("seek bar value----->"+progress1);

 bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
     public void onClick(View v) 
    {
         if (c != null ) 
         {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) 
                {
                    do 
                    {                       
                         year = c.getString(Column1);

                         System.out.println(year);
                         if(label.equalsIgnoreCase(year))
                         {
                             Log.i("","values compared....");
                             System.out.println("Lable.."+label);
                             System.out.println("year.."+year);
                             b=1;

                            }

                    }while (c.moveToNext());

                } 
            }
    }

});

} 
catch (SQLiteException se )
{
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
} finally
{
    if (sampleDB != null) 
        sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
        sampleDB.close();
}
}


public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch)
{
    progress1=progress;
       mProgressText.setText(progress + " " +getString(R.string.seekbar_from_touch) + "=" + fromTouch);
   }

   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
   {

   }

   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
   {

       progress2=progress1;
       System.out.println("seek bar value---->"+progress2);
      // upDate();
       sampleDB.execSQL("UPDATE "+SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME+ "SET Value= "+ progress2+ "WHERE Year="+label,null);



   }


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

     label = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
    System.out.println("selected values--->"+label);


 //  Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
{


}
public void upDate()
{
    if(b==1&&progress2>0)
     {
      b=0;

      sampleDB.execSQL("UPDATE "+SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME+ "SET Value= "+ progress2+ "WHERE Year="+label,null);
        Log.i("","database updated");
     }
}


}
```

Now my issues is i want to update database with select year from the spinner and adjustable slider value. Otherwise i have to change pie chart based on adjustable value with particular selected year. It shows some error.

```
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1793)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.exae.url.PieChartDefalut.onStopTrackingTouch(PieChartDefalut.java:283)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.widget.SeekBar.onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:115)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:302)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
     09-24 13:06:14.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

How can i resolve this problem? Can any body help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is complaining that the second argument to [`execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) is null.

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    progress2=progress1;
    System.out.println("seek bar value---->"+progress2);
    sampleDB.execSQL("UPDATE "+SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME+ "SET Value= "+ progress2+ "WHERE Year="+label, null);
}
```

You can just use [`execSQL(String sql)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    progress2=progress1;
    System.out.println("seek bar value---->"+progress2);
    sampleDB.execSQL("UPDATE "+SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME+ "SET Value= "+ progress2+ "WHERE Year="+label);
}
```